# Remote Sql Server connection with MSSMS

Tags: sql-server, remote-access

I am trying to connect to a remote sql server. I write the IP a.b.c.d into a server name, then I put username `test` and password `test`. This account has all `Server Roles` selected (I also tried with another account which only had `public`) and the databases I want to allow the user to manage (in `User Mapping` section) also have `public` and `db owner`. I have completed all the steps in [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) and I got it working on my local network with another computer in LAN having the server set up.

The error I get looks like this:

```
===================================

Cannot connect to a.b.c.d.

===================================

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

===================================

The user name or password is incorrect
```

But I can connect with the same credentials in the server itself, so I assume either: something is configured in a wrong way or I have to write the login name in some different fashion.

My both MSSQL programs (in two different computers) were installed with `SQL Server 2012 Standard` and `SQL Server 2014 Express` and the one I am trying to connect to is `SQL Server 2008 R2 Express`. However, at work, I have no problem connecting with version of MSSMS being different from the Server, so I doubt it is the case.

**Any ideas what I am missing/doing wrong?**

Comment: Same issue, can connect to computer\MSSQLSERVER2012  but not the default 2008R2 instance